# JS event function being fired only once

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a simple form validator for a Handlebars template. So, I used addEventListener on blur to validate the inputs but the event is being fired only once. Am I doing this right? Or is there a better way / recommended good practice for this ?

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jj4fsn9j/

```
function addInputValidation(el, event) {
    el.addEventListener(event, function() {
        var data = {
            invalid: {}
        };
        data.invalid[el.id] = false;
        data[el.id] = el.value;

        console.log(el.value);
        if (typeof el.value === 'undefined' || el.value === '') {
            data.invalid[el.id] = true;
        }

        console.log(data);
        updateTemplate(data);
    });
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With each `onblur`-event you are calling `updateTemplate(data)` which in turn leads to this line:

```
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = html;
```

Which means that everytime the event is fired, you overwrite the entire document with new content. Therefore, all the event handlers get lost.

See [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj4fsn9j/1/) where i - just as an example - have removed the `updateTemplate()` function. You will notice that here the event handlers fire accordingly, as many times as needed.

It is not good practice anyway to overwrite your entire document with every firing of an event. Either overwrite only the part of it that requires overwriting, or - if you need to stick to overwriting the entire document - make sure that you run `addInputValidations()` again after you change the `innerHTML` of the body. Again, i would like to stress though, that overwriting your body's content over and over is bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. And wow I did not see that. I feel embarrassed :p 
Thanks, I will try different ways to validate than overwriting the entire html.